Google Chrome Triggers Microphone Alert
For some reason, Google Chrome is triggering the microphone alert even if I have no extensions installed and I am on the start up screen. Crazier still, this notification persist even after I quit chrome. What's going on?


Are you sure google chrome hasn’t installed some background agents? Also, can we presume this happens immediately after you restart before you launch chrome? Or does it happen only when the main app starts? (Or only after a while, not immediately?)

Well you could try disallowing Chrome from using the mic but that's not really a fix as you might need to use it.
